flutter how to run mqtt client do not make UI janky?
Using flutter mqtt_client package, init client like this:
_client =
MqttServerClient.withPort(host, cid, 1883, maxConnectionAttempts: 3);
  kLog(
      '!!!! ------------> [conn] connect with $host, $port, $username, $password, $_clientId $_client');

  // _client!.logging(on: true);
  _client!.logging(on: false);
  _client!.onConnected = onConnected;
  _client!.onDisconnected = onDisconnected;
  _client!.onUnsubscribed = onUnsubscribed;
  _client!.onSubscribed = onSubscribed;
  _client!.onSubscribeFail = onSubscribeFail;
  _client!.onAutoReconnect = onAutoReconnect;
  _client!.onAutoReconnected = onAutoReconnected;
  _client!.pongCallback = pong;
  // _client!.keepAlivePeriod =
  //     1; // short enough in case client can not notify server offline
  _client!.autoReconnect = true;
  _client!.useWebSocket = useWebsocket;

Since the code actually runs barely in flutter, they are a while - loop along with main UI thread.
As all we know, flutter is single threaded (correct me if wrong), my situation is, when network getting slow, I think mqtt might got some connect issue, and my UI will get janky.
I tested about 2 years, this issue haven't resolved.
Anyone knows why and how to resolve it?
